# How to trim ',' in a string on c#

Tags: c#, string, trim

So I have this weird problem..

I have used `String.Trim()` to remove a comma in a string array `body[]` and then place it in another string `trim`:

```
string trim = body[i].Trim(',');
```

(where string body[i] = 3,500)

and it returns the value of `trim` still as `3,500`....

What could be the problem?
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What research did you do before asking this question?

Comment: next time try reading the documentation before asking a question

Comment: @LVBen - I have searched on how to trim characters in the internet..I have 0 idea on what a leading or trailing characters are..that's why I still used `string.trim()`...It's my bad I haven't searched more..
Should I just delete this question???
I think it's just a dumb question...

Comment: @Selman22 - yes sir!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx):

> Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters
>   specified in an array from the current String object.

Because the comma after the 3 is neither a leading or a trailing character, it does not get trimmed.  Try `string.Replace` instead.